# use $http service in app config when use ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i use angular ui router and coach potato in project, i want ui router states load from server side and add to state provider in angular app.Config, but can not inject $http service into app.Config function, my code like this :

```
var app = angular.module('app', [ 'ui.router.compat']);
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$routeProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$http',
  function ($stateProvider, $routeProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $http) {

      $urlRouterProvider
        .when('/c?id', '/contacts/:id')
        .otherwise('/');

      $routeProvider
        .when('/user/:id', {
            redirectTo: '/contacts/:id'
        });

      var get = $http.get('/api/Values/');

      get.success(function (data) {
            list = data.result;
        });

      var populateStates = function () {

          angular.forEach(list, function(item) {
              $stateProvider.state(item);

              angular.forEach(item.subMenus, function(sub) {
                  $stateProvider.state(sub);
              });
          });
      };

      populateStates();
  }]);
```

how can get data(states) from server in app.Config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The bottom line is:

- You CANNOT inject a service into the provider configuration section.
- You CAN inject a service into the section which initializes the provider's service.

### Details:

Angular framework has a 2 phase initialization process:

**PHASE 1: Config**

During the `config` phase all of the providers are initialized and all of the `config` sections are executed. The `config` sections may contain code which configures the provider objects and therefore they can be injected with provider objects. However, since the providers are the factories for the service objects and at this stage the providers are not fully initialized/configured -> **you cannot ask the provider to create a service for you at this stage -> at the configuration stage you cannot use/inject services.** When this phase is completed all of the providers are ready (no more provider configuration can be done after the configuration phase is completed).

**PHASE 2: Run**

During `run` phase all the `run` sections are executed. At this stage **the providers are ready and can create services -> during run phase you can use/inject services.**

### Examples:

**1. Injecting the $http service to the provider initialization function WILL NOT work**

```
angular.module('myModule').provider('myProvider', function($http) {
    // SECTION 1: code to initialize/configure the PROVIDER goes here (executed during `config` phase)
    ...

    this.$get = function() {
        // code to initialize/configure the SERVICE goes here (executed during `run` stage)

        return myService;
    };
});
```

Since we are trying to inject the `$http` service into a function which is executed during the `config` phase we will get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $http from services
```

What this error is actually saying is that the `$httpProvider` which is used to create the `$http` service is not ready yet (since we are still in the `config` phase).

**2. Injecting the $http service to the service initialization function WILL work:**

```
angular.module('myModule').provider('myProvider', function() {
    // SECTION 1: code to initialize/configure the PROVIDER goes here (executed during `config` phase)
    ...

    this.$get = function($http) {
        // code to initialize/configure the SERVICE goes here (executed during `run` stage)

        return myService;
    };
});
```

Since we are now injecting the service into the service initialization function, which is executed during `run` phase this code will work.

**Note: This is Shamelessly Copied from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497006/use-http-inside-custom-provider-in-app-config-angular-js)**

Comment: tnx for answer, but how can call service before config compelete, because i want get states from server and add to stateProvider