# Injecting service which define by module.provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, provider

Sorry to ask something like this, but i m already spend couple of days to solve this one.
But i m really need help. I am already read [Understanding Dependency Injection](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Dependency-Injection/) 
and also other stack question [use $http inside custom provider in app config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497006/use-http-inside-custom-provider-in-app-config-angular-js) use the
$injector
 on run block also not work in my code.

Perhaps someone here can help me, i am also worried how annotate the injection on my provider for minification.

```
My code in
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/qeBGDR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `$http` in the `_getItem` you are in the "controller". A solution could be to do this:

```
  this.$get = function($http) {
    return {
      mainUrl : _mainUrl,
      getItem : _getItem,
      httpWrapper : $http
    };
```

And then in the `_getItem` assign (or use the httpWrapper directly):

```
var $http = this.httpWrapper;
```

In order to avoid problems with the minification, you could add the injection to the method `$get`:

```
  this.$get =   ['$http', function($http) {
```

Here the updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/m7oXNolo6iV8Zy1NJ0vx

**EDIT**: I think that what you wanted to achieve is this:

```
  var _getItem = function() {
    var _d = null;
            console.log(this)
    var $http = this.httpWrapper;
    var $q = this.qWrapper;
     _d = $q.defer();
    $http.get(_mainUrl)
    .success(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      _d.resolve( {data: data, x: "efe"} );
    })
    .error(function(status) {
      _d.resolve( status );
    });
    return _d.promise;
  };
```

`$q.defer()` allows to defer the http call to your controller, then on your controller you have to edit this:

```
facade.getItem().then(function(data){
  $scope.myReturn = data;
}
```

`Updated Plunker`: http://plnkr.co/edit/xR1d3KnWhX51jHHZ8t3m

**Note**: Consider that the nature of `then` is asynchronous, thus if you use the variable straight afterwards, it still will be undefined

Comment: ok thanks dude, it works. But can you tell and give me example again? Because when i want create a defered object on the local scope, it's got undifined. i want 1 defered object on the local scope.

Comment: ok thanks, i mark it. But any reference? i got problem when try make costume callback(error and success) on the service and call it on the controller (attach the respone or error message to $scope)

Comment: For $q and defer, you can check this: http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2014/02/04/angularjspart-11-promises/.