# angularjs custom module with $http injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I need to write an angular module that uses $http

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myModule', []);

    app.provider("$late", function () {
        var file;
        var remoteFile
        var data = {};
        var separator;

        return ({
            $get: instantiateLate,
            Load: Load
        });
        function Load(config) {
            console.log("load");
            this.file = (config.file !== undefined) ? config.file : "";
            this.remoteFile = (config.remoteFile !== undefined) ? config.remoteFile : "";
            this.separator = (config.separator !== undefined) ? config.separator : ".";

            if (this.remoteFile === undefined && this.remoteFile === undefined)
                throw new Error('Specificare un file locale o remoto');

            //$http.get ....
        }
        function instantiateLate() {
            return ({
                file: file,
                remoteFile: remoteFile,
                data: data,
                separator: separator
            });
        }
    });

}());
```

How can I use the $http?
When I uncomment $http.get I get this error:

> ReferenceError: $http is not defined

thanks

Comment: what are the angular files you are using? and what does your module registration look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with this code it works

```
var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);
var $http = initInjector.get('$http');
```

Answer (score 2):

To fix your error, you need to inject $http.

```
app.provider("$late", ['$http', function ($http) { ... }]
```

Edit: However, since you are using a provider, you cannot inject a service into it. You can inject it in your $get though. **Instead of the above for a provider, use the following.**

```
    function instantiateLate($http) {
        return ({
            file: file,
            remoteFile: remoteFile,
            data: data,
            separator: separator
        });
```

Source: [use $http inside custom provider in app config, angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497006/use-http-inside-custom-provider-in-app-config-angular-js)

Comment: when I do this, this is the new error: "unknown provider: $http"

Comment: I updated my post. It turns out you cannot inject a service directly into a provider.

Comment: your link source has given me the correct way, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For providers, runtime service instances are injected in the `$get` constructor function.

```
$get: ["$http", instantiateLate($http)],
```

This means your code needs to be re-factored to work.

```
   function instantiateLate($http) {
       //
       //Put functions that uses $http here
       // 
       return ({
            file: file,
            remoteFile: remoteFile,
            data: data,
            separator: separator
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. The providers don't uses `return` statement for create the instance. check the correct way to create a provider in [this docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) and [this article](http://www.learn-angular.org/#!/lessons/the-provider-recipe).

My recommendation it's do the follow:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myModule', []);

    app.provider("$late", function () {
        var file;
        var remoteFile;
        var data = {};
        var separator;

        var httpReference;

        this.load = Load;
        this.$get = instantiateLate;

        function Load(config) {
            console.log("load");
            this.file = (config.file !== undefined) ? config.file : "";
            this.remoteFile = (config.remoteFile !== undefined) ? config.remoteFile : "";
            this.separator = (config.separator !== undefined) ? config.separator : ".";

            if (this.remoteFile === undefined && this.remoteFile === undefined)
                throw new Error('Specificare un file locale o remoto');

            httpReference.get('some_url');
        }

        instantiateLate.$inject = ['$http'];

        function instantiateLate($http) {
             httpReference = $http;
             return ({
                file: file,
                remoteFile: remoteFile,
                data: data,
                separator: separator
            });
        }
    });

}())
```