# Unknown $http Provider in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-routing

I need to use `$http` service in config method. But I can't use `$http` in config, I am getting `unknown Provider` error message.

My code :

```
.config(function($http, $routeProvider, $provide) {
    $http.get("sampleslist.js").success(function(data) {
        var loop = 0, currentRoute;

        for (loop = 0; loop < data[loop].pages.length; loop++) {
            currentRoute = data[loop].pages;

            var routeName = "/" + currentRoute[loop].name;
            $routeProvider.when(routeName, {
                templateUrl:"/" + currentRoute.name + ".html",
            })
        }
    })

    app = {controller: $controllerProvider.register}
})
```

Can you please provide the solution for this?

Comment: Well, as you said, you can't use $http in the config phase. You can use it in the run phase, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inject service in app.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937267/inject-service-in-app-config)

Answer (score 4):

It's not a good practice to use `$http` in the `.config`. One can use it either in `.run` or can make use of the service using either `.service` or `.factory`.

Comment: It is not about the practice. We can not inject $http in .config.

Answer (score 3):

If just need to make AJAX request you can actually retrieve $http server from the new injector:

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $provide) {
    var $http = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http');
    $http.get("sampleslist.js").success(

        function(data) {

            var loop = 0,
                currentRoute;

            for (loop = 0; loop < data[loop].pages.length; loop++) {

                currentRoute = data[loop].pages;

                var routeName = "/" + currentRoute[loop].name;

                $routeProvider.when(routeName, {

                    templateUrl: "/" + currentRoute.name + ".html",

                })
            }
        })

    app = {
        controller: $controllerProvider.register,
    }
})
```

Comment: $routeProvider.when(routeName, {                                                                                   
 
})

This function not hitting, why?

Comment: I wouldn't even suggest the OP circumvent the (intentional) limitation that Angular have put in; even then, `success` is a deprecated method and should not be used. Accessing `$http` in this way seems dangerous...

Answer (score 3):

We cannot use http in config. For more details please check this link:

[use $http inside custom provider in app config, angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497006/use-http-inside-custom-provider-in-app-config-angular-js)

Answer (score 3):

You can inject only providers in .config file. but $http is not provider, your angular app is searching for provider named $http but it is not able to find it so it threw error.

How to resolve this??

If you want any ajax call before your angular controller loading you can do it in .run

Comment: as per my knowledge/reading this is he flow of angular work. Above I meant to say is, You can run something before your controller loading. I should have mention data rather than page loading.
app.config()
app.run()
directive's compile functions (if they are found in the dom)
app.controller()
directive's link functions (again, if found)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have control over `sampleslist.js` ? If yes, maybe just download it using  tag and assign values to variables.

```
//sampleslist.js
var samplelist = {...}

//index.html
<script src="samplelist.js"></script>
```

Then you could inject this values to angular using `angular.constant` or just use variable `samplelist`