# Usinhg $http loader in angularjs config

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular config for loading routes.

```
app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", 
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        var states = [
            {
                name: "login",
                config: {
                    url: "/login",
                    pageTitle: "Login",
                    template: "<login></login>"
                }
            },
            {
                name: "app",
                config: {
                    url: "/app",
                    pageTitle: "Application",
                    template: "<app></app>"
                }
            }];

        states.forEach(function (state) {
            $stateProvider.state(state.name, state.config);
        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/app/index");
    }])
```

But I want to load `states` from server. So I need to use `$http` provider, but it does not work in `config`.

Comment: What do you mean? Why can't you use `templateUrl: 'assets/my-view.html'`

Comment: Why are you loading the states from the server?

Comment: I want to create a dynamic  menu table on database.

Comment: @bookmarker This is still unclear. What's wrong with the `templateUrl` property and a path to the file on the server?

Comment: @AlonEitan my states has 2 items as you can see in post. I will load these objects from server

Comment: @bookmarker Sorry to be a bore but I still not understand the issue (What about [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use $http inside custom provider in app config, angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497006/use-http-inside-custom-provider-in-app-config-angular-js)

Answer (score 0):

What will work for this scenario is **not** `$http` in `.config()`, but **`.run()`** and  **`$urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();`**. There is a documentation *(link and small extract)*

> #### [deferIntercept(defer)](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider)
>
> Disables (or enables) deferring location change interception.
>
> If you wish to customize the behavior of syncing the URL (for example,
> if you wish to defer a transition but maintain the current URL), call
> this method at configuration time. Then, at run time, call
> $urlRouter.listen() after you have configured your own
> $locationChangeSuccess event handler.

There are more details and working plunker https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013914/1679310