# How to pass information to angularJS config

Tags: angularjs, parameter-passing, angular-translate, angular-config

Hello I created basic angularJS app with angular-translate module. In config except my routing I've got also `$translateProvider` which is responsible for translations tables and prefered lenguage.

so this code:

```
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
```

is within Angular `config()` function.

I know that config is executed first, before `run()`, controllers and others. I also know that in config there must be only providers can't inject for example `$rootScope` there.

In my project by calling single endpoint using `$http` I gather information about country which user came into this app. This is happening in `run()`.

I tried to use `$rootScope` (in this `run()`):

```
$rootScope.homeCountry = response.data.country;
$rootScope.homeCountryLower = $rootScope.homeCountry.toLowerCase();
console.log($rootScope.homeCountryLower);
```

it console out "pl" in my case but I ended up learning that I can not pass `$rootScope` to config since it is not a Provider.

I need to pass this information to `$translateProvider` in config function so I would be able to set prefered user lengauge according to user country.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use $http inside custom provider in app config, angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497006/use-http-inside-custom-provider-in-app-config-angular-js)

Comment: Why is it duplicate?

Comment: Because he thinks your question has been answered over there already. After reading the accepted answer & comments I think so as well - since all I would have written here as an answer has been written there already.