# AngularJS Role Based Routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a pretty basic app and I'm having some permission problems. When the user logs in I save the session token in the localstorage.

After that, in my routing I have `/profile` and `/documentation`.

In my backend a user can have two roles: `normal` or `admin`. The **`normal` user should not have access to the `/documention` tab**. I'm hiding on the UI buttons based on the role but he can still go through the URL (problem).

**I just want to check if the role of the user is `admin` when accessing `/documentation`, otherwise redirect to a 403 page.**

Any ideas how to achieve this?

### app.js :

```js
let app = angular.module('GHoF', [
  'ngclipboard',
  'validator',
  'angular-jwt',
  'ngRoute',
  'bw.paging',
  'chart.js'
]);

app.config(function Config($httpProvider, jwtOptionsProvider, $routeProvider, ChartJsProvider) {

  // JWT
  jwtOptionsProvider.config({
    tokenGetter: function() {
      return localStorage.getItem('sessionToken');
    },
    whiteListedDomains: ['localhost']
  });

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');

  // Routes
  $routeProvider
    .when('/profile', {
      templateUrl: 'app/pages/profile/profile.html',
      controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
    })
    .when('/documentation', {
      templateUrl: 'app/pages/documentation/documentation.html'
    })
    .otherwise("/home")
});
```

```
app.run(function(authManager, jwtHelper) {
  authManager.checkAuthOnRefresh();

  let sessionToken = localStorage.getItem("sessionToken");
  console.log(sessionToken);
  if (sessionToken == null || jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(sessionToken) || !authManager.isAuthenticated) {
    window.location.href = "/auth.html";
  }
});
```

Login

```
let data = {
  username: $scope.username,
  password: $scope.password
};

$http.post("http://localhost:8083/api/login", data).then((res) => {
  
  localStorage.setItem('sessionToken', res.data.token); // JWT TOKEN

});
```

Comment: @georgeawg can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch and store the role of the user from the User service. Then use the user-role in routing as explained in this Stackoverflow question. I'm sure this is what you need to achieve.

[AngularJS routing based on roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47519787/angularjs-routing-based-on-roles)

Comment: I have to put a resolve in each when clause? I have like 50...

Comment: You only need the resolve to reject admin pages. Do you have 50 admin pages?