# Use of $rootScope value module.config throwing error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-rootscope

this is my app.config

```
  app.config(['$translateProvider',function ($translateProvider) {

      $translateProvider.useUrlLoader('/api/sitecore/translations/get?pageName=' + $rootScope.currentPage + '&');
}
```

when i run this I'm getting the error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=appModule&p1=Refere…%20at%20Zd%20(http%3A%2F%2Fathlonpoc%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A464)(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:6(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:38m @ angular.min.js:7g @ angular.min.js:37eb @ angular.min.js:40d @ angular.min.js:19Ac @ angular.min.js:20Zd @ angular.min.js:18(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:289a @ angular.min.js:176c @ angular.min.js:35
```

Please help me..I'm new to angularJs

Comment: You cannot inject stuff in the `config` phase: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682753/how-to-inject-a-service-into-app-config-in-angularjs

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Well, you can, but only constants and providers :)

Comment: Please tell if  there any other way to make that url dynamic.

Comment: @sp00m: yup, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You are Using $rootScope in code but you haven't Injected this dependency.

```js
app.config(['$translateProvider',function ($translateProvider,$rootScope) {

      $translateProvider.useUrlLoader('/api/sitecore/translations/get?pageName=' + $rootScope.currentPage + '&');

}
```