# Getting $injector:modulerr error while injecting $scope in angular-translate directive?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to inject $scope into angular-translate directive. But it shows

```
angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=navBar&p1=Error%3A%…eb%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fsrc%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A249)
```

the above error is encountering. I want to use `$scope` value from controller as `$translateProvider.preferredLanguage($scope.selectedLang);`

```
app.config(function ($translateProvider, $scope){
    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy(null);
    $translateProvider.translations('english', {
        'data': 'I am Ram'
    });
    $translateProvider.translations('telugu', {
        'data': ' \u0C28\u0C47\u0C28\u0C41 \u0C30\u0C3E\u0C2E\u0C4D'
    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage($scope.selectedLang);
});
app.controller('langTranslate', function ($scope){
    $scope.totalLang = ['english', 'telugu'];
    $scope.lang = 'english';
    $scope.selectedLang = 'english';
    $scope.$watch(function(){
        $scope.selectedLang = $scope.lang;
    });
});
```

If I remove `$scope` and `$translateProvider.preferredLanguage($scope.selectedLang);` `from app.config` it works fine. But I have to use `$scope` value there. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this question will help you understand what you need to do

[How to inject a service into app.config in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682753/how-to-inject-a-service-into-app-config-in-angularjs)

instead of app.config($translateProvider, $scope)

try it app.run($translateProvider, $rootScope)

```
    app.run(function ($translateProvider, $rootScope){
    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy(null);
    $translateProvider.translations('english', {
        'data': 'I am Ram'
    });
    $translateProvider.translations('telugu', {
        'data': ' \u0C28\u0C47\u0C28\u0C41 \u0C30\u0C3E\u0C2E\u0C4D'
    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage($rootScope.selectedLang);
});
app.controller('langTranslate', function ($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.totalLang = ['english', 'telugu'];
    $scope.lang = 'english';
    $rootScope.selectedLang = 'english';
    $scope.$watch(function(){
        $rootScope.selectedLang = $scope.lang;
    });
});
```

Comment: no. Getting this error
`Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24translateProviderProvider%20%3C-%20%24translateProvider`

Comment: did you load the translate provider?
did you include the translate provider to you angular.module?

Comment: Everything is done. If use a value, for example, `$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('telugu');` directly, it works fine. but I have to pass variable from the controller. So what should I do?

Comment: try putting it on a $rootScope.variable

Answer (score 0):

Please find the documentation for config here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Inside config block you can only inject Providers.

In order to work with it, you can use `$rootScope` provider because `$scope` is module.

Hope it helps you!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can not ask for instance during configuration phase - you can ask only for providers. for more information read this [guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

```
app.config(function (MyFactory){
    console.log(MyFactory.test);
});
app.factory('MyFactory', function(){
    return {
      test: 'testing'
    };
});
```

Comment: you can use it via factory.. see this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828287/what-things-can-be-injected-into-others-in-angular-js

Comment: here you can access a variable in config.