# $http inside config in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I have some config that route to different views. It is hardcoded for now. There is var "a" and ifit equals to 1 it redirected to view1. But i want to set there $http and to route according to result.

How could i insert $http inside config?

This is my js:

```
angular.module('mainPage', [
'mainPage.controllers',
'ngRoute','kendo.directives'
]);

angular.module('mainPage').config(function ($routeProvider) {
  //Here i want to put my $http.

    var a = 1;
    if(a==1){
        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1' });

    }else{
     bbb   
    }
    $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
        controller: 'Controller1',
        templateUrl: 'partials/validation.html'
    }).when('/view2', {
        controller: 'Controller2',
        templateUrl: 'partials/guests.html'
    });
});

angular.module('mainPage', [])

.controller('Controller1',function($scope){

    $scope.source = [
        {nav_id:1,nav_name:"Validation",nav_src:"validation"},
        {nav_id:2,nav_name:"Guests",nav_src:"guests"}
    ];

})
.controller('Controller2',function($scope){
    $scope.now=new Date();
});
```

and this is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>html { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />

    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div   ng-app="mainPage" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <ng-view></ng-view>
 </div>
    <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main_page.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to put something like this:

```
$http({/
        url: 'aaa/aaa/aaa',
        method: "GET",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        }
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject into config, but for sure put this stuff into the 'run' block.

```
app.run(function($http) {
     // use $http
})
```

[how to inject dependency into module.config(configFn) in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286588/how-to-inject-dependency-into-module-configconfigfn-in-angular)

Comment: But config is bootstrapped before run. I need $http and then config

Comment: Well, you can't. Config is for providers only.