# ng-Route doesn`t work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, ngroute

i have a problem with my code with ng-route. Adress in browser is changing but on my page all elements are still the same. Here is my code:

```js
var app=angular.module('mainApp',['ngRoute']);
app.config('$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
      .when('/',{
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
      })
      .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'about.html'
      })
      .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'contact.html'
      })
      .otherwise({ 
   redirectTo: '/'
   });
});

app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope){

    });
```

```html
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
 <div>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/about">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/contact">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
   </nav>
 </div>
   <br/>
 <div ng-view ></div>
</div>
```

i have three subsite with simple  paragraphs (home, about and contact. html).

Can you help me?

Comment: may be `url` is not correct.

Comment: my main HTML is Desktop/SS/index.html#/ if i click About us this is changin on Desktop/SS/index.html#/about but on side in nothing happens. If i delete Url from templateUrl everything is correct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In a comment you mention that `Desktop/SS/index.html#/` is your main page. Therin lies your issue.

Routing does not work unless you serve up the pages through an HTTP server. Looking at your HTML pages statically on your file system won't work unfortunately.

If you have Python on your system, you are able to test this out really easily: open a command prompt and change to the `Desktop/SS/` directory. Then run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` and go in a browser to http://localhost:8080. It should work perfectly that way

Comment: @ernest did you try this?

Comment: thanks for tip. I had to strat it by localhost. Now everything is working ;)

Answer (score -1):

Please use `app.config( function ( $routeProvider )` instead of `app.config('$routeProvider', function ( $routeProvider )`

**script :**

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
      .when('/',{
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
      })
      .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'about.html'
      })
      .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'contact.html'
      })
      .otherwise({ 
            redirectTo: '/'
            });
});

app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope){

    });
```

`Demo Fiddle` : https://jsfiddle.net/jLdce3vj/43/

Comment: Hmmm... i have angular library "Angular.min.js" and "Angular-route.min.js" but if i instead app.confing on your proposition this still doesn`t work ;/

Comment: Yes i got the issue in your code. I updated my answer please check the `jsfiddle`. It is working fine. I made some correction in your code.

Comment: This is not a good idea. If you do it the way you are suggesting, $routeProvider will be removed during minimization and will not work. The code in the original question is correct, as it will allow Angular to do proper dependency injection

Comment: @JaronThatcher, I totally agree with you but it is not defined in question that he will go for minimization of the code. I am just trying to suggesting my answer. This is not a reason to downvote my answer.check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286588/how-to-inject-dependency-into-module-configconfigfn-in-angular and first think before downvote the answer.

Comment: @Rohit Jindal,  if you click on every link in jsfiddle, your home page replace to about page and contact page?? Because at my place it doesn`t work all the time on page is "Home page"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add something in fiddle. Thanks for correcting me. Now, you can check the updated fiddle its working fine.

Comment: @Ernest, You checked ?

Comment: @Rohit Jindal, yeeah now it is working :) thanks a lot :)